# "#orderedlist > li" selector

Tags: jquery

I'm studying jQuery with [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery) tutorial, but one of examples doesn't work.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      a.test { font-weight: bold; background: #fc0 }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#ol > li").addClass("test");
        $("#some").addClass("test");
      });
    </script>
    </head>
   <body>
     <a href="http://jquery.com/" id="some">Some</a>
     <ul id="ol">
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

This example apply the "test" style to hyperlink (#some), but doesn't apply this style to the ordered list (#ol).  Why?

Comment: Just a comment - that demo seems confusing. Why give a UL element an ID of ol, which is the name of a list container element?  I know it's not your demo, but I wanted to point out that it's confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove the `a` from

```
a.test { font-weight: bold; background: #fc0 }
```

The a limits it to links (anchor tags).

Answer (score 4):

The JavaScript is OK, the CSS isn't. The CSS rule only applies to links.

To see the effect, change the CSS to:

```
.test { font-weight: bold; background: #fc0 }
```